# Не удалить ссылку

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет! Мне надо сделать так, чтобы нельзя было удалить ссылку.
Допустим, я выложил шаблон в паблик с ссылкой. Конечно же, все ее удалят.. Мне надо так, что при удаление ссылки шаблон не работал!
Реализация на любом язык: js/php и т. д.

Comment: Хахаха. Все б так сделали.

Comment: Способа, который никак не обойти, не существует.

Comment: Просто продавайте шаблоны в нормальных странах)

Comment: **не будьте жадиной**

Comment: Вариант всяких "лайков" (типа как в фейсбуке) пойдет? Т.е. создаете шаблон, указываете ему параметры, значения которых будут его заполнять. Выкладываете ссылку на шаблон с описанием параметров.

Или не лайки, а прогноз погоды, например.

На сто процентов не защитит, но если ссылке динамически назначать стили/теги, то это будет проблематично.

Либо лицензию какую-нить приплюсуйте. Т.е. "имеете право пользоваться только если не удалите ссылку". А потом судитесь с теми кто воспользуется и удалит))

Comment: Ссылки они все удалят, смысла нет. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы я разместил там ссылку php/js и она там осталась..

Comment: А то, что "не будьте жадиной" полный бред, я целый день делал шаблон. А потом слить просто так в паблик?! Нет уж, спасибо.

Comment: Самый надежный способ - это не выкладывать. Вы же целый день мучились. Но можете выложить в виде картинки. Кому нужно - обратятся, дадите. Но в том то и дело, что html/js текстовый и отредактировать можно.

Comment: Ссылку можно получать с сервера вместе с другой информацией. Если с клиента идёт ajax запрос, то там следует также передавать эту ссылку и на сервере проверять корректность к лицензии, если неправильная, то сервер не отвечает.

Конечно и это можно отключить, только поняв что придётся возится, на 99% человек перейдёт к другому шаблону.

Comment: Шаблон я солью в паблик, но оставлю ссылочку. Возможно это сделать через PHP?

Comment: @bifot, вы попробуйте удалить ссылку из кнопки "like". Можно, но придется попотеть.

Еще один абсурдный вариант - реализовать шаблон на канвасе, а JS обфусцировать. И это можно будет обойти, но тоже непросто.

И еще - а что именно мешает выложить это в открытый доступ? Тот самый "полный бред"?

Сомневаюсь, что хэшкод был написан за "целый день", но вы ведь пользуетесь им, и пользуетесь бесплатно. То же самое с jQuery и остальным. Они в открытом доступе, кому от этого плохо стало?

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал один известный блоггер:
 - чтобы у вас ничего не крали с сайта, разместите на нем что-нибудь никому не нужное.

Html шифровать достаточно бесполезно: любые попытки это сделать будут натыкаться на беспроблемное чтение через firebug. 
Один из вариантов - разбить на кучу шаблончиков, которые будут сшиваться обратно скриптом.

Теперь по ссылке: чтобы ее не удаляли, разместите ее в неочевидном месте, либо в незаметном. Простейший(только для примера!) вариант - белым текстом на белом фоне.
Можно "прошить" реквизиты в каждую картинку шаблона(цифровой водяной знак, не путать с полупрозрачным барахлом поверх картинок), либо в названия классов:

```
.bifot-div{
}

.b-if-ot{
}

b, i, .fot{
}
```

Создайте md5-хэш, разместите на своем сайте, а только через некоторое время кладите в паблик. Тогда время первого появления в сети и исходный хэш будут зафиксированы именно за вами.

Наконец, просто продайте кому-нибудь конкретному за определенную сумму на определенных условиях.

Comment: Насчет "продайте". Уже точно не помню, вроде как в Америке какое-то изобретение было продано где-то за 1 американский доллар. Это "какое-то" изобретение в итоге принесло купившему его миллиарды прибыли.

Я бы локти после этого кусал)

Comment: Таких изобретений много. Чтобы не кусать локти, можете в договоре описать ваш процент с прибыли. Это в любом случае лучше, чем выложить в открытый доступ и не получить ни копейки. ^_^ Но это уже увод дискуссии в сторону коммерции. Я же написал это с нажимом на то, что за сохранностью материала будет следить кто-то еще, так как он же вложил свои кровные туда!

Comment: Огромные территории американского континента были выкуплены у коренного населения за вещи общей стоимостью 25 долларов. Вот уж кто должен локти кусать)

Comment: @fori1ton у них теперь весь игровой бизнес в сша, а недавно кое-кто выгнал из племени всех черных, раздал всем оставшимся по $200k на лицо и пообещал "вернуть себе Манхэттен, который вы купили у нас за бусы" =) И никто их не засудил, чсх. Но это скорее исключение, конечно)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать зашифровать, но спешу огорчить, что все что зашифровано можно расшифровать(Идеальной защиты нет). Вот пример первый вариант от гугла [зашифровка html-документа](http://pr-cy.ru/html_encrypter).

Comment: если это "шифрование"... то мне страшно:)

Comment: Вот это шифрование (на самом деле обфускация, но не суть) выглядит поинтереснее: http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html

А вот в этой статье прицесс такого шифрования описан подробнее: http://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/128741/